# How do I convert ISO 8061 to Datetime in PHP?

Tags: php, date, youtube-data-api, iso

I'm using the YouTube API and when I try to get the video duration the I receive `PT11M41S`, so an ISO 8061. How can I get a PHP Date Object?

Comment: That's a duration, not date/time. `PT11M41S` means `11 minutes, 41 seconds`. What result are you expecting to get?

Comment: $duration = new DateInterval("PT11M41S");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already said yourself , you tried to get duration from Youtube API.Then the format you receive is not at all datetime but a duration (as expected ) based on [ISO 8061 specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601#Durations) .You can't simply convert this kind of duration to Datetime in PHP .That would be useless.However you can convert it to PHP DateInterval native object this way:

```
$duration = new DateInterval("PT11M41S");
```

From there you can format it as you want(in a human readable design) using the `DateInterval::format() function`
To know more about how to construct and use PHP DateInterval object you can take a look at :[The DateInterval class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)